# bash -x command

Tags: bash

I saw a client doing `$bash -x` command to see if the file is executable (or `ksh -x` command, etc.) like the `-x` in the `if` statement in the shell script.

My question is: **What does `$bash -x` command do?**

My interpretation was to start a command in a new bash shell within the current shell, inheriting the same environment variables and executed by the same user.

The funny thing is I can do `$ls` but not `$bash -x ls`, which give:

(under AIX 6)
`/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file`

It is a mystery for me why the error is - guessing it is due to a privilege which means my assumption above is not correct.

Also, I believe `$bash ls` and `$bash -x ls` is the same thing (`-x` for "execute")?

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: to execute a bash command with debug mode (-x) enabled, use `bash -x -c your_command`

Comment: Thanks Alex for the concise answer, bash -x -c ls does what you described. So, "$bash -x command to see if the file is executable" is the WRONG then :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Khiet If you want to find out if a file is executable than just type `ls -l command`

Comment: @Tomas, yeah the funny issue we are having at the moment is a binary with -rwxr-xr-x gives "cannot execute binary file". Checked owner/group, possible corruption but no luck so far. Anyway, not expecting to get my entire job sorted here :) Cheers!

Comment: @KurzedMetal Exactly XD, will be careful.

Comment: to check if a file is executable use `[ -x file_in_question ]` in bash which will return 0 if it is executable. You can otherwise check what type the file is by using `file file_in_question` to get a verbose description of the file contents

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `-x` option starts a BASH shell in tracing mode. You can see all the details of how your command/script is processed. It's a good way to find some bugs if your script does not do what you would expect to

And, just as Alex said [in a comment](/q/10107124#comment-12948907), to run a command in BASH, you have to use `-c` option like `bash -x -c ls`.

See `man bash` or the online manual, specifically the parts on [invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) and [the `set` builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) for more information:

> All of the single-character options used with the `set` builtin (see The Set Builtin) can be used as options when the shell is invoked.

> #### `-x`
>
> Print a trace of simple commands, `for` commands, `case` commands, `select` commands, and arithmetic `for` commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the `PS4` variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, man for bash isn't installed on our VM but man page online does actually say it all ;( thanks for everyone for such a quick answer, much appreciated!

Comment: @Khiet You're welcome. If you don't have man installed, type `man bash` into Google and the first link is usually the manual page :)

Answer (score 9):

- **`bash -x <file>`** runs the script `<file>` with tracing of each command executed
- **`test -x <file>`** tests whether `<file>` has execute permissions for the current user.

It appears that you have muddled these two.