# read interactive prompt in a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate some mundane stuff I have to do with bash, but I'm running into trouble with debugging. Basically when I run interactively the script runs fine, but when I submit the job to a batch system whatever I'm running prints

```
Please answer yes or no.
```

multiple times. The problem is that I have no idea what it's asking me. Is there some way to direct the prompt to be printed so I can debug this?

Comment: Have you tried [`bash -x`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107124/bash-x-command)? Basically, `bash -x -c your-script.sh`.

Comment: hmm, that's theoretically useful, but the problem is that bash is executed by the batch system. Is there some way to turn that option on once I'm in a script?

Comment: hmm, so it seems there is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/951352/915501

Comment: yes `set -x` and `set +x`

Comment: still doesn't really help, this just tells me that the method calls a python script. I'd imagine that python somehow prints a prompt, but I can't seem to view it.

Comment: Doesn't the batch system give you a capture of stdout when it runs your job? How about result files? you could redirect stdout to a file in the script with `exec >file`

Comment: Workaround: try to execute as `/bin/bash -i myscript.sh` and/ or to put `#!/bin/bash -i` as 1st row... you can try to cheat it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is in sort of need for a TTY, my workaround is this one:

```
have_tty()
{
    tty >/dev/null 2>&1
    return $?
}

say()
{
    if have_tty; then echo $@; return; fi
    logger -i -t restart_libertas $@
}
```

Just replace

> echo

with

> say

and I think you're done