# use of flags in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Scripts in linux start with some declaration like :

`#!/bin/bash`

Correct me if I am wrong : this probably says which shell to use.

I have also seen some scripts which say :

`#!/bin/bash -ex`

what is the use of the flags -ex

Comment: On bash terminal, run `help set` for more details on these flags...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

<=>

#!/bin/bash
set -e -x
```

Man Page (http://ss64.com/bash/set.html):

```
-e  Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero status, unless
   the command that fails is part of an until or  while loop, part of an
   if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return status
   is being inverted using !.  -o errexit

-x  Print a trace of simple commands and their arguments
   after they are expanded and before they are executed. -o xtrace
```

*UPDATE*:

BTW, It is possible to set switches without script modification.

For example we have the script `t.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "before false"
false
echo "after false"
```

And would like to trace this script: `bash -x t.sh`

`output:`

```
 + echo 'before false'
 before false
 + false
 + echo 'after false'
 after false
```

For example we would like to trace script and stop if some command fail (in our case it will be done by command `false`): `bash -ex t.sh`

`output:`

```
+ echo 'before false'
before false
+ false
```

Answer (score 4):

These are documented under `set` in the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section of the man page:

- `-e` will cause Bash to exit as soon as a pipeline (or simple line) returns an error
- `-x` will case Bash to print the commands before executing them

Answer (score 1):

```
-e
```

is to quit the script on any error

```
-x
```

is the debug mode

Check [bash -x command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107124/bash-x-command)
and [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script/19622569#19622569)