# How can I capture the raw command that a shell script is running?

Tags: bash, shell

As an example, I am trying to capture the raw commands that are output by the following script:

https://github.com/adampointer/go-deribit/blob/master/scripts/generate-models.sh

I have tried to following a previous answer:

[BASH: echoing the last command run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run)

but the output I am getting is as follows:

```
last command is gojson -forcefloats -name="${struct}" -tags=json,mapstructure -pkg=${p} >> models/${p}/${name%.*}_request.go
```

What I would like to do is capture the raw command, in other words have variables such as `${struct}`, `${p}` and `${p}/${name%.*}` replaced by the actual values that were used.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the script after the hashbang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash` (if there is any) add `set -x`

> set -x Print commands and their arguments as they are executed

Answer (score 0):

Run the script in debug mode which will trace all the commands in the script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107170/988525.

You can do that without editing the script by typing "bash generate-models.sh -x".

Comment: You need to pass the `-x` flag before the script name (that is, `bash -x generate-models.sh`).