# Bash -x or set -x

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there any practical difference in debugging using `bash -x scriptname.sh` or using `set -x` inside the script and then calling it?

In my personal experience I always use `bash -x` because that way I don't have to change the script so it's less invasive.

Is there a scenario where `bash -x` would not fit and just `set -x` would work?

I came up with these questions because I always see people suggesting `set -x` when trying to help others to debug and I was wondering why not `bash -x scriptname.sh`. Is there a technical limitation?

PS: I'm not asking about what the commands do, but I'm asking "how" they do and if one is better than the other.

About what they do:

- [bash -x command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107124/bash-x-command)
- [What does `set -x` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do)

Comment: `using set -x in terminal and then calling the script?` it won't work that way

Comment: @KamilCuk opps.. I will fix.

Comment: @lucasgvarela : Convenience: If you put it for debugging inside the script, you have to use an editor, and if you are done, you have to remove it or comment it out. Doing it from the command line, when running the script, allows you to set it "on the fly".  Another difference is that `bash -x` also traces the startupfiles, which are listed in the INVOCATION section in the bash man page. This makes a difference, if you, for instance, also use the options `--login` and/or `-i`.

Comment: Just because Google brought me here when I wanted to know this "set -x enables a mode of the shell where all executed commands are printed to the terminal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason to avoid things in the shebang is that *strictly* a POSIX kernel doesn't have to support more than one argument. So `#!/usr/bin/env bash -x` may not work (`#!/bin/bash -x` may, but then you may be using the ancient bash on macOS, for example). (That said, many UNIX-like systems do, in fact, support shebangs with multiple arguments.)

If you're dealing with security or secrets options at the first part of your script, but you want to be able to debug later on, you may want to `set +x` for the security related section. But, you can always do `set -x` so that is not a particularly robust reason to avoid `bash -x`.

Comment: Given that OP says they don't have to modify the script, I'm guessing they're asking about running `bash -x myscript` and not adding `-x` to the shebang

Comment: Also arguments within the Shebang will be by-passed by direct invocation by the interpreter like `bash scriptname`. So having `set -x` within the script or any other shell option, warrant the option will be set as intended, regardless if the script interpreter is called from the shebang or direct invocation.

Answer (score 5):

I would also suggest `set -x` and not `bash -x` to a user debugging a script.

- The user fully expects to modify the script to fix the bug, so adding a line is a non-issue.
- You don't have to know how the user runs their script (it could be via some build script or IDE, and not just `./foo` in a terminal)
- You don't have to confirm the shebang, since `#!/bin/bash -eui` would require you to instead run `bash -euix file` and `#!/bin/sh` would require `sh -x file`.

But for myself? Yeah, I'd just run `bash -x`.

Answer (score 1):

They are different interface to the same functionality, check out the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash):

> All of the single-character options used with the set builtin (see [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)) can be used as options when the shell is invoked.

The different is. Do I set it before the first line of the script gets evaluated (`bash -x ./script.sh`), or do I set it within the script (`set -x` anywhere in the script). They can both enable and disable the simple trace funvtionality, last `set` "wins" as in affects the lines that follow. There is no functional difference in the effect the two have otherwise.